# Read only files with certain extension from directories and sub-directories in C.

Tags: c

I have this code I modified but the problem is, I can't get it to jet me only files with certain extensions. I tried so many things and every time I don't get the desired output.  Any help would be appreciated. This part of a very big project and I got stuck at this specific function.

```
static void list_dir (const char * dir_name)

{



   DIR * d;

/* Open the directory specified by "dir_name". */

d = opendir (dir_name);

/* Check it was opened. */
if (! d) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
             dir_name, strerror (errno));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
while (1) {
    struct dirent * entry;
    char * d_name;

    /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
    entry = readdir (d);
    if (! entry) {
        /* There are no more entries in this directory, so break
           out of the while loop. */
        break;
    }
    d_name = entry->d_name;
      if(!strstr (d_name, ".jpg") == 0 && !strstr (d_name, ".JPG") == 0){
         continue;
     }
    /* Print the name of the file and directory. */
printf ("%s\n", d_name);


/* If you don't want to print the directories, use the
   following line: */

    //if (! (entry->d_type & DT_DIR)) {
    //printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);
//}


    if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {

        /* Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. */

        if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {
            int path_length;
            char path[PATH_MAX];

            path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,
                                    "%s/%s", dir_name, d_name);
            //printf ("%s\n", path);
            if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
              if(!strstr (d_name, ".jpg") == 0 && !strstr(d_name, ".JPG") == 0){
         continue;
     }
            list_dir (path);
        }
}
}
/* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
if (closedir (d)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
             dir_name, strerror (errno));
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

}

Comment: Tell me, what does `!strstr (d_name, ".jpg") == 0` do?

Comment: What do you get?  What do you expect?  Why do you expect what you get?  Can you build this into a self-contained program and test it?

Comment: immibis.  that was a typo in the original code I ran. I fixed that. That line is supposed to read  if((strstr (d_name, ".jpg") && strstr (d_name, ".JPG"))

Comment: No; it shouldn't read `if (strstr(d_name, ".jpg") && strstr(d_name, ".JPG"))` unless you only want to match single file names such as `MY.jpg.has.JPG`.  You need `||`.  @immibis nailed your problem; you mixed up `!strstr(d_name, ".jpg")` with `strstr(d_name, ".jpg") == 0`.

Comment: Jonathan; I expect only files with jpg extensions but I end up getting every file on my directory and subdirectory. One time I got only files that did not have jpg  extensions and when I changed the logic for that but negative  the strstr command, it did not help.

Comment: Jonathan: if (strstr(d_name, ".jpg") || strstr(d_name, ".JPG")) that's the code I had. I just copied the old one from a previous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should know that case sensitivity is not solved by just using `".jpg"` and `".JPG"` since there could be more like `".jPg"` and so on.

You can try this

```
int endsWith(const char *const filename, const char *const extension)
 {
    size_t fileNameLength;
    size_t extensionLength;

   if ((filename == NULL) || (extension == NULL))
       return 0;

    fileNameLength  = strlen(filename);
    extensionLength = strlen(extension);

    return (strcasecmp(extension, filename + filenameLength - extensionLength) == 0);

}
```

then you can do

```
if (endsWidth(d_name, ".jpg") != 0) /* it has jpeg extension */
```

**Note**: `strcasecmp()` is not standard, you can find the correct alternative for your c library googling.

And also, there are libraries that examine the file type by using the so called *magic* bytes, they are normally the first 4 or so bytes in the file content, there is even one called `libmagic`, although I have never worked with it, so I can't give you advice on how to use it.

Comment: Additional note: on Windows strcasecmp is called `stricmp`.

Answer (score 2):

I would replace the line

```
if(!strstr (d_name, ".jpg") == 0 && !strstr (d_name, ".JPG") == 0){
```

with more readable code:

```
if( fileIsNotJPGFile(d_name) ) {
```

And implement the function as:

```
int fileIsJPGFile(char const* name)
{
   return (strstr(name, ".jpg") || strstr(name, ".JPG"));
}

int fileIsNotJPGFile(char const* name)
{
   return !(fileIsJPGFile(name));
}
```